# Ao inves de abrir nova aba, ele faz download

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Estou usando o IE, e pra abrir nova aba, uso o window.open. O meu ie que é 11, abre a nova aba normalmente, mas em outro ie que tambem é 11 porem um pouco mais antigo, ele faz download, como posso resolver?

Comment: mande o código fonte.

Comment: Olá! IE 11 é IE 11. Não existe IE 11 mais antigo ou mais novo. Poderia melhorar sua pergunta postando o código que vc já tem?

Comment: A página que você está abrindo é html?